# Ubuntu not booting from USB; No "continue" option in the installer when choosing to install alongside Windows

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation

I have windows 8.1 installed on my laptop. I have burned Ubuntu 14.04.1 to USB. But when I restart my laptop & go to boot menu Ubuntu cannot boot from USB. I have done separate partition of 20 GB. Please help me to install from USB. I have also tried Wubi for 12.04 but it gives an error. I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows with dual boot.

**Update**

I have done booting from USB helping with answers. and now on installation step, when I choice "**Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8**", I have no "**Continue**" option button to continue installation.

Here is the screenshot of this step:

[image]

Comment: Did you make USB as first boot order in your BIOS settings? What happened when don't boot from USB, did you get any error?

Comment: no usb is bootable but when i select usb option in boot menu nothing happens..no starting of ubantu installation...

Comment: yes i am trying to install with usb 2.0 port I have lenovo G500 model & win 8.1. No black screen apears..

Comment: no...is it required to disable??

Comment: ok...it can be disable in bios settings??

Comment: I have disable fast startup & then try to boot from USB but then also no effect. when I press enter on USB drive in boot menu no process takes place & windows resumes...

Comment: k but where I can post image can u pls give me ur email id?? i can send it I have not my private blog..

Comment: http://imgur.com/50ZnmAr   here is boot snapshot..

Answer (score 1):

With windows 8 in addition to changing you boot order in your bios you must disable secure boot and OS Mode Selection (both in your bios) for it to recognize Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it compulsory to disable secure boot?? & how to change OS mode selection??